# Device cannot see pdf in assets folder

Tags: android, pdf

So I'm making an app that displays an app offline, without using an external pdf app.

I did so successfully by placing a pdf in my assets folder and displaying it using this tutorial:
http://upadhyayjiteshandroid.blogspot.com/2013/03/android-pdf-viewer-application.html

While this runs fine on the emulator, I do not know why it does not run on an actual device. The device does not have an SD card, I was hoping to just contain the file within the app so nothing else is needed.

```
File internalFile = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File[] fileList = internalFile.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
        public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
               return ((name.endsWith("bvcbook.pdf")));
        }
    });
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If your PDF is in assets, what does external storage have to do with anything?

Comment: The emulator reads the pdf fine, but when I switch to an actual device   it can no longer find it.

Comment: That does not answer my question. If your PDF is in assets, what does external storage have to do with anything? Why would something be looking for a PDF in external storage, if the PDF is in assets?

Comment: I just mentioned the SD card because I thought that maybe it was a possible cause of my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the pdf file in your /res/raw directory. Get it with getResources().openRawResource(R.raw
._your_pdf_id).

Comment: It can't seem to see my pdf with R.id.pdfName after I placed it in the res/raw folder. Ive tried, deleting and regenerating the R.java, restarting the eclipse, and rebuilding the solution.

Comment: I've also tried import packageName.R , and multiple file types in the raw folder. Is there another step besides placing it in the folder?

Comment: Here's why. Don't use R.id.yourfilename, use R.raw.yourfilename as the id of the file in the /res/raw directory

Comment: Still working on this, Ive got it working correctly thanks to your help but its frustrating to finally get it display properly from assets. Now I'm starting over completely to get it to display from R.raw. Why does it not work from assets?

Comment: You can put them in /assets but files in assets don't get a precompiled id like the /res directories do. If you put them in /assets it isn't as easy to access and is slower.

Comment: Is there an easy way to to view in the pdf with a pdfviewer when reading from res? Or just opening it with adobe reader from inside the app?

Comment: I figured out the problem, it was that my device had no SD card. Thanks for your help.